# Spark application going out of spark operator's reach

Tags: apache-spark, prometheus, grafana, metrics, spark-operator

I have a spark application "X" and it was appearing in my spark operator's prometheus metrics 60 days ago, However some redeployments happened to that application, and meanwhile it stopped appearing in Spark operator metrics. Looks like the spark operator is not able to communicate to the spark app. I get this log line for the apps that appear in metrics.

```
    {"log":"I0529 13:09:39.530545      10 controller.go:267] Starting processing key:
```

followed by app name.

```
    spark_app_running_count{app_type="X"}
```

For the above query app X, does not give any data in grafana. Does that mean that spark operator has lost the track of that app ? Whats the reason for this issue ? Any help is great. Thanks in advance .